# managing production credentials in heroku

Tags: git, deployment, heroku

we're deploying a heroku app to production. it accepts credit card numbers, so we have to be careful with the credentials that are in it. we use git for source control. if i were deploying to a regular server, i'd keep the production config files separately, and copy them in when deploying.

the problem is that heroku uses git to deploy, so i have to commit my production stuff to git to be able to deploy to heroku. how do you keep those files from then going upstream?

the only thing i've thought was to make a local fork of the repo, and hook the fork to git. not sure if i like that though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can set environment variables on heroku by using the **heroku** gem:

```
heroku config:add MYKEY=12345679
```

and you can use that in your heroku App using `ENV['MYKEY']`

See: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars